# Translation WorkBench What are negative affects of turning it on for an Org

Tags: custom-field, translation-workbench

To not change label names on some custom fields, would like to use Translation Work Bench to change the label for the English Language.  Is there any negative effect for turn translation work bench on?

Answer (score 1):

There are no negative side effects, though you'll want to read [Considerations for Managing Translations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workbench_best_practices.htm&type=5). However, as with most features, it is recommended that you first enable this feature in a Sandbox to make sure it is really the feature that you want to use.